# T SQL, breaking the loop once I found the records I needed

Tags: sql, t-sql, windows-server-2008

I m trying to read from temporary table using following query

```
select
    a,b,c, result, sampleDate
from dbo.abc
where
    a = @la and b = @lb and sampleDate > @lSampleDate and
    resultType in ('sugar','salt','peppers')
```

What i want to achieve is, once I found the matching rows, I want to stop reading the table, delete the rows just read and search the table again, find new values and so on.

I dnt understand how to stop it once I found my values.
e.g

```
    tsampledate     tResultType                     result
     10/08/2005          cream                        10.9
     10/08/2005          sugar                        10.0
     10/08/2005          Salt                         15.0
     10/08/2005          peppers                      20.0
     21/10/2012          sugar                        21.9
     21/10/2012          salt                         23
     21/10/2012          peppers                      19.3
```

so I want read with tSampleDate 10/08/2005, break the loop goes back to search again. but the loop keep reading and give me all the values.

was thinking of SELECT CASE but cant figure out how to implement.
any help please.

Comment: WHILE EXISTS ()  select top 1, delete from etc.

Comment: you want to delete the records you have found from the query?

Comment: Why don't you just DELETE..FROM..WHERE ? What are you trying to achieve with a cycle that you can't do querying directly your table?

Comment: I dnt know at what row I ll get tSampleDate > @lSampleDate

Comment: @De Lisi, delete part is not a problem, the records will be deleted after the I finish inserting where I want to insert. but that part is not problem.The problem is with the stopping the loop where I want to

Comment: The delete where condition should be crafted so that it matches all rows you want to delete. Row order won't matter. It will just leave the rows that don't match the condition. (the rows you want to keep?)

Comment: Can you show us the loop?

Comment: I think I made mistake, in the question where I said about delete the records, I ll delete the records after the insertion query, the while loop keep looking for the tSampleDate >@lSamppleDate

Answer (score 0):

The proper thing would be to

```
delete
from dbo.abc
where
    a = @la and b=@lb and sampleDate > @lSampleDate and
    resultType in ('sugar','salt','peppers')
```

Comment: thanks for reply, can u pls suggest some code how I ll stop the loop once I found three rows with one date i.e. 10/08/2005. I dnt want to read next values or dates once I found my first set of values. I hope u understand

Comment: I guess you are calling this delete routine not manually from SQL editor, but from some application. Do this stopping in that application instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for first match that satisfies sampleDate > @lSampleDate and ..

i.e '10/08/2005' then Try this

```
SELECT a,b,c, result, sampleDate 
FROM 
(
  select
    a,b,c, result, sampleDate
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sampleDate) AS rnk
  from dbo.abc
  where
    a = @la and b = @lb and sampleDate > @lSampleDate and
    resultType in ('sugar','salt','peppers')
) t
WHERE rnk=1
```

check this Ranking function [**DENSE_RANK**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

Comment: you almost solved my problem!If I put 'break;' after 'where rnk=1', I got the set of rows I need.my full problem: I have #tmpTable1, I read the values using while loop 1, then I have to go to next #tmpTable 2, I am trying to read through the loop 2, and I am using lSampleDate, la, lb from #tmpTable 1. then I start reading from #tmpTable 2 by passing above variables, inside this second loop, I need to get set of rows with sDate>lSampleDate. by implementing your solution and putting 'break', returns me result set.

Comment: but it does break the two loops. and If I dnt put 'break', the loop does not stop nor give me any output!! any solution for breaking only inside loop at once